# Book for Blender

Tags: animation

Kindly suggest book title and author name by which I able to learn blender completely and make animations if you have share the link of this book it is helpful for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It would be easier to learn through youtube tutorials (there are a lot of good ones, check Grant Abbit for example). For books make sure that they are recent, at least from 2.8 and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

The software is just a tool, animation is learned independently. The first two classic books are:

- *The Animator's Survival Kit* by Richard Williams
- *Disney Animation: The Illusion of Life* by Frank Thomas and Ollie Johnston

Both considered as the Bible of animators. They are the two giants pretty much every western animator has to read or even consult on a daily basis.

Then you can go to some more precise domains, such as *The Artist's Complete Guide to Facial Expression* by Gary Faigin. It's not about animation itself, but facial expressions, which are essential for any acting shot. Or why not *Game Anim: Video Game Animation Explained* by Jonathan Cooper that's more specific for animation in the video game industry.